# Date dropdown field selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing

I'm working on an application with dropdown field date selection.

- Clicking Month will trigger Day dropdown field to re-arrange to available days
- Clicking available days will caused the Time dropdown field to re-arrange to available time slots
- Clicking the available time in the dropdown will trigger an application form display/open.

I use the below code to select Month instead of `click` and it failed to trigger the Day dropdown field to react for re-arrangement.

```
cy.xpath('//*[@id="AvailableMonths"]').find('option').then($elm => 
        $elm.get(2).setAttribute('selected', "selected"));
```

I want to click future month, day and time but i have no idea of how to approach it.

I have done some google search and most of the option were pointing to react-select-event and i have no idea of how to make use of it. Kindly help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue with the below approach

```
cy.get('element option')
    .eq(3)
    .then(elm => cy.get('element')
    .select(elm.val(), {force: true}))
```

Any other approaches are welcome pls.